# Angular Karma/Jasmine testing: How to mock a service in controller with promises?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test my controller. The function that I am trying to unit test is:

```
    function myFunction() {

        MyService
            .myMethod(thing1, thing2)
            .then(function handleMyMethod(result) {
                SomeModule.errorHandler(result)
                    .onSuccess(function onSuccess() {
                        // do stuff
                    })
                    .onError(function onError() {
                        // do stuff
                    });
            });
    }
```

Relevant test file snippet:

```
var MockService = {
  myMethod: function(thing1, thing2) {
   var promise = $q.defer().promise;
   return promise;
 }
};

beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('MyService', MockService);
}));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _MyService_, _SomeModule_, ...) {
  ...
  MyService = _MyService_;

  MyController = _$controller_('MyController as Ctrl', {
    $controller: controller,
    MyService: MockService,
  });
```

I am confused about how to write tests that allow me to hit both the onSuccess and onError cases. I am trying to cover both branches for branch coverage, but don't know how the syntax works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it one of two ways:

1. You can write your mock service to look at the parameters and resolve with an error or success.

```
    myMethod:function(thing1, thing2) {
        if (thing1=='all good') return $q.when('excellent');
        return $q.reject('sorry, bud');
    }
```

2. You can override the method closer to where you're calling it.

```
it('is a success', function() {
    spyOn(MockService, 'myMethod').and.returnValue($q.when('excellent');
    $rootScope.$apply(
        MyController.doStuff('foo');
    );
    expect(MyController.someProperty).toEqual('excellent');
});
//etc.
```

Note you don't need to both override the module injector with the provide code and provide the mock service in the $controller locals parameter.

Comment: For method #2, is the error case the same except $q.when('excellent') becomes $q.reject('error') ?

Comment: Yes. Please note that $q.reject doesn't exist in all versions of angularjs, so you may still need to use $q.defer().reject('error') if you're working in 1.2 or something.

Comment: My angular version is 1.3, so it looks like I had to use $q.defer().reject('error'). My success case works, but my error case doesn't like the  MyController.doStuff('foo'); line. My error test case is identical to the success case, except for the  $q.defer().reject('error') line. Are there any other changes that I need to make?

Comment: Did you use the callFake or the override?

Comment: I used #2, the override solution that you provided. I do not have any callFake in my controller.